# Change color of Nativescript+Angular progress bar

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'd like to change the color of the highlighted part of the progress bar to red, and the background color to blue.

Setting the "color" property as follows, changes both:

```
<Progress [value]="progressValue" maxValue="6" (loaded)="onProgressLoaded($event)" color="red" class="m-t-20 m-b-10"></Progress>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Adding the "backgroundColor" property makes no visible difference...

Any ideas would be helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `color` and `backgroundColor` properties programmatically in your `onProgressLoaded()` function :

```
onProgressLoaded(event) {
  event.object.color = "red";
  event.object.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Working example here : https://github.com/mickaeleuranie/nativescript-stackoverflow-46904518

Comment: Thanks @micster! Awesome! -- Do you know why using the css background-color, or adding "backgroundColor='blue'" to the progress markup doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

for fully customized progress bar you can use -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-number-progressbar

Comment: Yes, that would work. However if I can make do with less plugins, I prefer that.